Sound Lost After Updating To 24.04.1
I discovered that I'd lost sound after updating to 24.04 today.
I tried reinstalling pulseaudio and alsa, changing alsa's config file and several other things I can't recall.
Yet nothing works. My sound is stone dead.
What the hell is wrong here with the software (since the hardware worked fine till this morning) in Ubuntu 24.04.1 that it fails to convert these digital streams to real sound ?

have you tried apt update and if nothing updates did you try sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^ (note it will reinstall desktop) in my case there was some alsa settings that were installed. This was after the 24.04.1 update.

Somehow today my Sound Settings show 4 options instead of just the 2 offered yesterday.

Once I selected one of the 2 new options, i.e. those offering built-in audio, I recovered my sound.
Where did these new options come from ?
Most likely from one or other of the config file changes made last night . . . e.g. snd_soc_avs, etc.
Despite several reboots yesterday no change in audio options was noted.
Can anyone enlighten me more ?
